# How do I make turtles stop at certain line?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

So I've created a simple race game with Turtle graphics and I have one issue.

There are 5 Racers. They all start from (-600, y) and when the first one hits the finish line(600,y), I want 5 of them to stop and, declare the winner(I haven't written that part yet) afterwards. This code doesn't do what I wanted it to do though. Sometimes they all stop after 3-4 of them passing the finish line, sometimes none of them passes the line and they all stop. I'm relatively new to Python and discovered turtle 2 days ago. Can anyone tell me where did I do wrong? I want to finish this asap and move on to better modules.

```
import random
import time
from turtle import *


wn = Screen()
wn.bgcolor("cyan")
wn.title("Turtle race!")

class Racers(Turtle):
    def __init__(self,color,pensize, shape,position,):
        super().__init__(shape)
        self.penup()
        self.color(color)
        self.pensize(pensize)
        self.shape(shape)
        self.setposition(position)
        self.pendown()

positions = ([-600,200], [-600,100],[-600,0],[-600,-100],[-600,-200])

racers = [
    Racers("black", 1, "turtle", positions[0]),
    Racers("red", 1, "turtle", positions[1]),
    Racers("yellow", 1, "turtle", positions[2]),
    Racers("blue", 1, "turtle", positions[3]),
    Racers("purple", 1, "turtle", positions[4])
]

def draw_finish():
    finish_line = Turtle()
    finish_line.penup()
    finish_line.shape("classic")
    finish_line.color("black")
    finish_line.shapesize(1)
    finish_line.goto(600,-300)
    finish_line.left(90)
    finish_line.pensize(10)
    finish_line.pendown()
    finish_line.forward(600)

def race():
    while True:
        for racer in racers:
            distance = random.randrange(1,20)
            racer.forward(distance)

        if racer.xcor() > 600:
            time.sleep(5)
            break

draw_finish()
race()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is caused by this code:

```
    for racer in racers:
        distance = random.randrange(1,20)
        racer.forward(distance)

    if racer.xcor() > 600:
        time.sleep(5)
        break
```

You're moving all the racers, before testing for a winner, by as much as 20 pixels.  Two or more can easily cross the finish line before testing.  We can rearrange this to be:

```
    for racer in racers:
        distance = random.randrange(1,20)
        racer.forward(distance)

        if racer.xcor() > 600:
            time.sleep(5)
            return
```

This quits when the first one crosses the finish line.  But it does give a slight advantage to the first racer in the list.  We can throw in a `shuffle` to fix that.  Below's my rework of your code with these fixes and some style tweaks:

```
from random import randrange, shuffle
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

positions = ([-600, 200], [-600, 100], [-600, 0], [-600, -100], [-600, -200])

class Racer(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, color, pensize, shape, position):
        super().__init__(shape)

        self.color(color)
        self.pensize(pensize)
        self.speed('fast')

        self.penup()
        self.setposition(position)
        self.pendown()

def draw_finish():
    finish_line = Turtle()
    finish_line.hideturtle()
    finish_line.speed('fastest')
    finish_line.pensize(10)

    finish_line.penup()
    finish_line.goto(600, -300)
    finish_line.pendown()

    finish_line.setheading(90)
    finish_line.forward(600)

def race():
    while True:
        shuffle(racers)  # so 1st in `racers` has no advantage

        for racer in racers:
            distance = randrange(1, 20)
            racer.forward(distance)

            if racer.xcor() > 600:
                return

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(1300, 650)
screen.bgcolor('cyan')
screen.title("Turtle race!")

draw_finish()

racers = [
    Racer('black', 1, 'turtle', positions[0]),
    Racer('red', 1, 'turtle', positions[1]),
    Racer('yellow', 1, 'turtle', positions[2]),
    Racer('blue', 1, 'turtle', positions[3]),
    Racer('purple', 1, 'turtle', positions[4])
]

race()

screen.exitonclick()
```

See if this provides the exciting turtle racing action you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but sorry it didn't work. I mean I've tried it a couple of times its obviously better than before but this happens too: https://imgur.com/a/Gdqpj3i

Comment: @BoraBircan, confirm that with my unmodified code -- what you're showing has been modified from my original.

Comment: Oh you're right I apologize, I did a minor mistake with indentation. It works now, thank you.